# Localized resources with ReactJS and server side rendering Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, reactjs

I'm building a site with React and Asp.Net MVC. The site needs to be multi-language, I was planning on using the classic resx files for that.
I started doing this

```
@Html.React("FriendListContainer", new
{
    initialData = Model,
    getUrl = "/Friend/Get",
    deleteUrl = "/Friend/Remove",
    resFriends = Global.Friends // pass resource as prop
})
```

It works, but is far from ideal as this makes the code harder to read. Also I need to pass these props all the way down to the components that need them..

I tried using [React-Intl](http://formatjs.io/react/) but it does not work with server-side rendering. I would rather not go back to client-side rendering if possible.

How could I make this work without making my code look so clunky ?